# Custom Android build script in eclipse that behaves differently for release and debug without ant

Tags: android, eclipse, scripting, build

I have created a custom build script in python that changes some strings in my strings.xml. But now I need it to change some other strings depending on whether it is a release or debug build. I can't seem to find a variable that I can send as parameter to the script that differentiates between the two.

I want to avoid going over to ant if at all possible, since we have build servers and all kinds of stuff that need changing then too.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to test the app's signature at runtime. You could load different strings based on that result:

[How to make Android app automatically configure w/ debug vs. release values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289775/how-to-make-android-app-automatically-configure-w-debug-vs-release-values)